# Find Mercurial Changes Where Both Parents Are In The Same Named Branch

Tags: mercurial

I'd like to list all changes in a Mercurial repo that are merges where both parents are in the same named branch as the change itself.

I.e., merges that are *not* from one named branch to another.

I know how to list all merges:

```
hg log -r "merge()"
```

But I'm having trouble figuring out how to express "both parents are in the same named branch as the change itself".

Answer (score 0):

This is best I've come up with so far, but it only works if you can specify the branch name (`default` in the example below).

It doesn't seem to include any changes it shouldn't, but I can't say that it's not excluding changes it shouldn't.

```
hg log -r "children(p2(branch(default)) & branch(default)) & branch(default) & merge()"
```

Any feedback or better answers are welcome!

Comment: Wouldn't that just include the `default` branch and not any other named branches?

Comment: @Јοеу Good point! I'll edit the answer to include that limitation.

Comment: 1. In order to be more wide solution, revset must be in [revsetalias] with branchname as parameter 2. My six sense tells me, that this revset **must** fail in common case, while it OK in hgsubversion repo

Comment: Part 2: Preparation of revset's logic. `children(p2(branch(default))`  **degenerates directly** into  `merge() & branch(default)`. Sequent ANDing have to do nothing, AFAICS. You must test (in pseudo-code( "if branch(p2(...)) eq branch(children(p2(...)", I think